# Solution to the Equation $x^x = 0$.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w, tetration, power-towers

If I solve the Equation $x^x = 0$, then I get $x^x=0$:

x ln⁡(x)= -∞
or
ln⁡x $e^{\ln⁡(x)}$ =-∞

and if we take the Lambert W function on both sides we get

ln⁡(x)=∞,

And I put it on Wolfram Alpha then it shows undefined? Is $x^x$ never equal to zero,or is it in a complex domain?.

Comment: There in fact are no solutions. However, be very careful with function application. $\ln0$ is not $-\infty$, it is just undefined.

Comment: But if you see this link here https://byjus.com/questions/what-is-the-value-of-e-power-minus-infinite/, then they are saying that e^-infinity = 0, then ln(0)=-infinity.

Comment: $e^{-\infty}$ makes no sense and is definitely not equal to zero. It is the limit of exponential function $e^{-x}$ which is zero when x tends to minus infinity i.e.  As @DonThousand said, $\ln0$ is not defined, since the domain of natural logarithm function is (0,$\infty$) and clearly $0\notin$ this domain. For the same reason $e^{-\infty}$ is not defined too

Comment: @DonThousand $\log(0)=-\infty$ is pretty standard; it's the continuous continuation of $\log$ to the [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), the same with $\exp(-\infty) = 0$.

Comment: @Hyperplane I agree, and I said just this in a comment under the deleted answer. But, this only restricts the operations one is allowed to do even further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you ask: "What are the solutions to this equation?" one crucial component is to specify over what admissible solution space you are looking for solutions. This is because equations can have a wastely different number of solutions depending on what kind o *"x"* we allow.

Take $x(x^2+1)(x^2-2)e^{x} = 0$ for instance. Over the integers, this has a single solution: $x=0$. If we allow real numbers, then also $\pm \sqrt{2}$ are solutions. If we allow complex numbers, then $x=\pm i$ are solutions as well. If we allow the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), $x=-\infty$ is a solution. If we allow [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), then there are infinitely many solutions. If you allow $x$ to be an element of some matrix space, you can get all sorts of solution sets.

And if you are unsure of what the solution space should/could be, then it is also important to mention that, since quite often possible to extend the space somehow to get solutions.

Now, in the case at hand we have

$$0 \overset{!}{=} x^x \overset{\text{def}}{=} e^{x\log x} $$

Now over the reals, there is no solution. Over the extended reals, $e^x = 0$ is achieved for $x=-\infty$. However $x\log x=-\infty$ has so solution over the extended reals. If we allow ourselves to extend further into the complex domain, we have $\log(z) = \log(re^{i\phi}) = \log r + i\phi$ for any complex number $z$.

Taking $z=-r = re^{i\pi}$ we have $z\log z = -r(\log r + i\pi) \to -\infty$ as $r\to\infty$, so one could say that $x=-\infty +0i = \infty \hat z$, where $\hat z=e^{i\pi}\in S^1$ is a solution in a sort of "extended complex plane".

Note that this is a different kind of extended complex plane than the [Riemann Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), which you'll find if you google for this term. The Riemann sphere is obtained by gluing all points at infinity together into a single point, whereas here, we attach a circle of so-called [directed infinities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity) $\{\infty\cdot \hat e_z \mid |\hat e_z|=1 \} = \infty \cdot S^1$ to the complex plane.

We can verify numerically that $x=-\infty$ this is a solution in python:

```
import numpy as np

for x in np.linspace(-1+0j, -100+0j):
    print( x**x )
```

Converges against $0$ very quickly. Note that we have to add the $0j$ to make sure python treats it as a complex number, otherwise you will get errors!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

Any positive number raised to a positive power gives a positive number. So, $x^x$ is always positive in $\mathbb R^+$.

For, negative $x$, that is, in $\mathbb R^-$, the function $x^x$ cannot be defined. This is because $(-2)^{-2}$ doesn't make any sense (in $\mathbb R$).

At $x=0$, the function $x^x$ is simply not defined as $0^0$ is undefined.

That is why $x^x=0$ has no solution in reals.

Now, let us consider $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ defined as $f(z)=z^z$. If we consider $z=a+ib$, then the modulus of $z^z$ is $(a^2+b^2)^{\frac a 2}.e^{-b\arg (z)}$, which can never be $0$. This proves that $f(z)=0$ has no solutions.

In case you don't understand, how I got the modulus, check [complex exponentiation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html).

Comment: OP hasn't said whether they want real or complex solutions (although the result is the same regardless) so if I were you, I'd edit to include a proof that there is no solution in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @DonThousand okay, I'm adding that

Comment: @DonThousand Okay now?

Comment: FYI, (-2)^(-2)=1/4. I understand that you are looking to make a point about staying out of the complex numbers, but there is no issue with raising a negative integer to a negative integer, as that is just the inverse of the positive exponent. Something like x=1/2 is a better example

Comment: @Aidan Yes, the thing is it's hard to point out that subset of $\mathbb R^-$ on which $f(x)=x^x$ is defined

Comment: For one, all negative integers work. See the [tetration spindle](http://klotza.blogspot.com/2015/11/the-sophomores-spindle-all-about.html). The real values are where the spindle “pokes through” the real xy plane.

Comment: @TymaGaidash That's a nice link! I never knew that.